# Are there any right SQL formatting patterns?

Tags: sql, formatting

I want to write right SQL queries and I need to know the standards of SQL formatting. I don't mean logic or efficiency, I mean right indents and spaces. Also I interesting in case of the commands.

Are there any right SQL formatting patterns(standards)?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114346/algorithm-for-formating-sql-code

Comment: There aren't many formal standards, though I suspect that there's at least one Celko book that covers it a bit.  You can look through the code in questions tagged [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), and more particularly at the answers, to see how people format SQL for presentation here.  The questions are often less well formatted than the answers.

Comment: Good idea. I'll follow your way to learn... But there are too much different ways to do it right. I want to choose one and follow it. I like Java because it has a defined standards of code format and naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Database Coding Standard and Guideline](http://www.nyx.net/~bwunder/dbChangeControl/standard.htm). It's outdated since 2008, but I can't find something better yet. I'm looking for this some months ago and seems really nice.

I was looking at oracle and mysql sites, but the "monsters" never published a formal paper.

Answer (score 1):

well I'm not starting discussion about uppercase table names now, but most often you will think about how to format select / update / insert / delete statements. In the document giben by Pablo Dominguez they suggesting to format select like this

```
select      t.Task_Id,
            t.Course_Id,
            t.Due_Dt,
            t.Start_Time,
            t.End_Time,
            t.Name,
            et.Completed_Flag,
            et.Completed_Dt
from BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK t
inner join BusyWork.dbo.ENROLLMENTTASK et
on t.Task_Id = et.Task_Id
where t.Due_Dt >= @pStartDate
and t.Due_Dt <= @pEndDate
and et.Member_Id = @pMemberId
order by    t.Due_Dt,
            t.Start_Time
```

I can say it's very hard (for me) to read such a script, especially the `from` part, so in our system we're using conventions like this

```
select
    t.Task_Id,
    t.Course_Id,
    t.Due_Dt,
    t.Start_Time,
    t.End_Time,
    t.Name,
    et.Completed_Flag,
    et.Completed_Dt
from BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK as t
    inner join BusyWork.dbo.ENROLLMENTTASK as et on t.Task_Id = et.Task_Id
where
    t.Due_Dt >= @pStartDate and t.Due_Dt <= @pEndDate and
    et.Member_Id = @pMemberId
order by t.Due_Dt, t.Start_Time
```

In `update`, `delete` statements I always trying to write `from` clause, so I always can easily rewrite `update`/`delete` into `select` to test it

```
update BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK set
    Due_Dt = getdate(),
    Name = 'updated'
from BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK as T
   inner join BusyWork.dbo.ENROLLMENTTASK as et on t.Task_Id = et.Task_Id
where
    t.Due_Dt >= @pStartDate and t.Due_Dt <= @pEndDate

delete BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK
from BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK as T
   inner join BusyWork.dbo.ENROLLMENTTASK as et on t.Task_Id = et.Task_Id
where
    t.Due_Dt >= @pStartDate and t.Due_Dt <= @pEndDate
```

In `insert` statements, I'm trying to avoid `values` clause, so I also can easily rewrite statement to plain `select`. Always explicitly specify columns in the insert to avoid problems after adding/removing fields from table. Also try to use alias for column name, so you can check right values when you testing it with plain `select`

```
insert into BusyWork.dbo.TB_TASK
(
    Due_Dt,
    Name
)
select
    getdate() as Due_Dt,
    'New' as Name
```

Another one rule - always use aliases for columns and tables/view/table functions. It will be easier to modify statement in the future and it can help you to avoid some nasty bugs when changing tables schema.

Comment: I don't like Pablo's Dominguez way too. Yours is better. But it's just SELECT example.

Comment: I don't think I like your style to "*avoid values clause*". I think this makes the intention much more confusing (and not all DBMS allow a SELECT without a FROM).

Comment: Well yes, it may be not suitable for other RDBMS, but for SQL server I like it very much. It's not confusing at all and it much more easy to support and maintain such a code

Comment: I don't like the syntax of the SELECT statements in my publication, but Pavel need some papers that not exists with much more explanations than a SELECT